# Powershell extract Time property from Variable

Tags: powershell

I have this Query:

```
$cpuTime = (get-wmiobject Win32_Process -filter "commandline like '%STRING%'" -computername $server)
$cpuTime | % { $_.ConvertToDateTime( $_.CreationDate )}
```

How do I extract just the "time" (hh,mm,ss) from the `$cpuTime` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a string, you can call ToString with a [custom date and time format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
$x = (get-wmiobject Win32_Process )
$x | % { $creationDate = $_.ConvertToDateTime( $_.CreationDate ); $creationDate.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}
```

You could call [DateTime.TimeOfDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a Timspan back that represents elapsed time since midnight.

```
$x = (get-wmiobject Win32_Process )
$x | % { $creationDate = $_.ConvertToDateTime( $_.CreationDate ); $creationDate.TimeOfDay} |
Select-Object Hours, Minutes, Seconds
```

Comment: thank you!
this is working, just to add to the problem.

is there a way to use this variable to retrieve how long the process has been running for the current time?

Comment: If you have admin privileges on the machine, you can get the `KernelModeTime` and `UserModeTime` and add them to get the total number of ticks (100ns units) the process has been alive for. You can divide this by `[TimeSpan]::TicksPerSecond` to get this in seconds.

Comment: You could just do something like `$now = ( get-date )` when you start and then in the loop just do `$elapsed = $now - $creationDate`.  Then just use the pieces of `$elapsed` that you need.